# Birt now showing up tables in create data set form

Tags: eclipse, birt

I am trying to create a data set (BIRT) in eclipse. I tested connection with the data source. It is successful. But while trying to create data set, data set form does not show up tables in data base.

I even tried firing query anyways, but eclipse freezes then.

Please suggest, if anyone has encountered similar problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem. BIRT needs Informix Jdbc driver to be installed in a particular way. So even though java code was able to read and write from Informix, BIRT was getting stuck.

I thought driver can not be a problem as java classes were working fine with the same drivers.

Hope this helps.